# Do Azure Kubernetes nodes share clock / NTP server?

Tags: azure, ntp, azure-aks

Do machines in Azure's Kubernetes service share the same NTP server(s) and, therefore, keep the same time? I'm looking for accuracy to the second or better (ms, etc.)

This is regarding AKS, but I know they have other Kubernetes offerings too.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I read documents and find one that I think it's interesting and particular to you. Azure VM is based on Hyper-V and they synchronize time from the host where they are. You can get the details from this document: [Accurate Time for Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/accurate-time).

Comment: The article explicitly says "Applies To: Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 10 or later"... do you think it also applies to ACS/AKS/acs-engine machines as well?

Comment: According to the document, it also applies to the VM host on it, including Linux. And AKS machines actually are Ubuntu VMs, so I think it also applies to AKS machines.

Comment: Can you see that description? And what do you think about the ACS/AKS/acs-engine machines time?